# Как сделать градацию серого, соответствующую определенному числу в C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, цвета, picturebox

Сейчас я рисую черный квадрат в picterBox

```
SolidBrush MyBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle);
g.FillRectangle(MyBrush, 10, 10, 200, 200);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне надо задавать оттенок серого этого квадрата с помощью чисел от 0 до 255. Т.е. значение 0 должно представлять черный цвет, а значение 255 — белый. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень просто:

```
SolidBrush MyBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(Красный, Зелёный, Синий));
```

Т.к. у Вас градации серого, то `Красный == Зелёный == Синий`, т.е. при создании кисти передавайте Ваше заданное число в функцию `FromArgb`

Пример:

```
int value = 165;
SolidBrush MyBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(value , value , value ));
```